# YoutubeplayerSupportFragment and actionBarActivity

Tags: android, fragment, android-youtube-api, android-actionbar-compat

What i am trying to do is put the `Actionbar` with home upenabled in the `Activity` with the youtube playersupportfragment. I have the code in `Xml` as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVideoTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/red_color" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvVideoTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVideoDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

the above video fragment plays the video jst fine when i have this code.

---

```
public class YoutubeVideoView extends ActionBarActivity implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener{

private YouTubePlayerView youtuber;
private TextView videoTitle, videoDesc;
private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment;

private int index;
private ArrayList<String> titles, ids, details;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube_video_view);
youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(developerKey, this);
```

---

now here the line `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`; is commented but if i uncomment it shows the error. I'm posting the errror below

---

```
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.def/com.abc.def.YoutubeVideoView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:66)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at com.abc.def.YoutubeVideoView.onCreate(YoutubeVideoView.java:34)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-19 21:44:48.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1303):     ... 11 more
```

---

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to access the actionbar after the setContentView method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `youtubeBaseActivity` rather than using `ActionBarActivity`. If you want to use actionbar activity, use different `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` with action bar activity.

Comment: because it is not importing youtubebase activity methods in here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Robin were you able to find a solution to this ? if so please share the code for it or any other solution, thanks !!!